# Multi-step Firebase Authentication Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement an angular6 webapp using Firebase authentication. I have been able to get the basic firebase authentication working but here is the issue I am having. Once a user authenticates with Firebase, I need to make a request to my backend to get some further information on my user from the database:

```
    @Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private endpoint = '/api/user';
    public user: InternalUser;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private httpClient: HttpClient) {
      console.log('[UserService] Instantiating user service.');
      this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          console.log('[UserService] Auth State Changed.');
          if (user) {
              this.updateUserInfo()
                  .subscribe((curUser: any) => {
                      console.log('[UserService] curUser: ', curUser);
                      this.user = {firstName: curUser.first, lastName: curUser.last, roles: curUser.roles};
                  });
          }
      });
  }

    updateUserInfo(): Observable<InternalUser> {
      console.log('[UserService] Updating user info @ ', this.endpoint);
      return this.httpClient
        .get(this.endpoint)
        .pipe(
            map((body: any) => body),
            catchError(() => of('Error, could not load user.'))
        );
  }
}
```

And my authentication guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private userService: UserService) {
    }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if (this.afAuth.auth.currentUser) {
            console.log('fb user found');
            return true;
        }
        return this.afAuth.authState
            .take(1)
            .map(user => !!user)
            .do(loggedIn => {
                if (!loggedIn) {
                    console.log('access denied');
                    this.router.navigate(['/pages/auth/login']);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I'm very new to Angular and this works but the issue is the firebase authentication completes and allows a user into the site before my user service is able to finish its request to get more information on the user (such as roles). Obviously in the auth guard right now it is only checking the firebase authentication so this is to be expected, I'm just not sure how to change it around correctly. I tried to look at the angularfire2 library and copy the observables set up to make my user service mimic their auth service but I couldn't quite understand how it works. Looking for any tips on the user service / auth guard or if I should take a step back and be doing this differently.

edit: Here is my login method, I'm just calling the firebase authentication:

```
login() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.value.email, this.loginForm.value.password)
            .then(credentials => {
                console.log('[Login] Login success!');
                this.router.navigate(['/'], { replaceUrl: true });
                this.isLoading = false;
                if (this.loginForm.value.remember) {
                    console.log('[Login] Saving credentials because remember = ', this.loginForm.value.remember);
                    this.afAuth.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log('[Login] Successfully changed persistence to LOCAL');
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log('Unable to update persistence: ', error.message);
                        });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.loginForm.controls['password'].setErrors({'invalid': true});
                this.loginForm.controls['email'].setErrors({'invalid': true});
                this.onLoginFormValuesChanged();
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
    }
```

The reason I wanted to accomplish this in the auth guard is so if a user reopens other pages it would have a chance to reload the details first.

Comment: would be helpful to see your login page. I would just check everything there and forward the user only if it all works out like you want to. If not, just log the user out again... like `if loginbutton clicked, get me all the infos and only if i am happy, foward the user, else, log user out again`

Comment: Added login method to main post